# Is there a way to switch user in powershell to run a command without password prompt?

Tags: powershell

I want to log off a user on a remote machine using the powershell code:

```
$session = ((quser /server:$system | Where-Object { $_ -match $user }) -split ' +')[2]
logoff $session /server:$system
```

Currently these commands are executed by account : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM but i want to execute the commands using another user.

I have tried using :

```
runas /user:administrator /savecred "quser /SERVER:$server"
```

but it prompts for password, I want to execute the script automatically . Is there any way I can switch the user without having to pass the password through terminal?

Comment: If you could do this, it would be a major security flaw. Any malware could do the same thing, bypassing providing the proper credentials for administrator. Does that make sense that it would be possible? *Gee, let's just allow things that require admin privileges to be done without a password. Nothing could go wrong with that, could it?*

Comment: @KenWhite Totally agree with you. Is there any way I could pass credentials , taking account name and password from user, I believe we cant pass Credentials directly into command i.e runas /user:administrator "quser /SERVER:$server" -Credential $Cred

Comment: have you tried using `Invoke-Command -Credential $(Import-Clixml $CredentialFilepath) -ScriptBlock {quser.exe} -ComputerName $server`?

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz I have tried using this command , it is executing the command from NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user , not from the entered credentials. I have checked the user using "[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name" command and it is still returning  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me say that this is not a good idea for many security reasons, one of them being that if someone gets access to your script it will have access to your password. Anyway, what you want to do is not possible but you can implement a workaround.

Instead of "run a command without password prompt" if you know the password you can "fake" a user typing it into the prompt, this will not suppress the prompt but will write the password as if someone was actually typing it on a keyboard.

To achieve this you can use the `SendKeys` function, it essentially fakes a key press.
The idea is to wait for the password prompt to show and then send the password character by character faking a keystroke.

As an example this will send the keys `H` and `i` and then press `enter` as if someone physically typed them.

```
#Write some text
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Hi")
#Press on Enter
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Unfortunately my knowledge finishes here since I've never actually used it successfully but always relied on manual input.

Comment: @KenWhite never said it's a smart idea, I simply stated how he may be able to achieved what he wants. That's why I wrote "

First of all let me say that this is not a good idea for many security reasons, one of them being that if someone gets access to your script it will have access to your password". No point in being condescending...

Comment: @KenWhite Well from how I see it is that if we just write "nope can't be done" he's gonna just search somewhere else until he finds it, might as well tell him a way to do it and say it's really unsafe. As long as he uses it to log into his rpi at home and not in the nuclear launch code system it's fine by me if he wants to risk it.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSmith , I won't be hard coding password in the script itself , the script can fetch password from a secure file using Export-Clixml and Import-Clixml. I just want to know can we switch user by passing credentials directly to command like using -Credential $Cred